# Countability of quasicomponents/components/path-components

Tags: general-topology

Is there an example of a space $X$ for each of?:

- $X$ has $\beth_0$ quasicomponents and $\beth_1$ components
- $X$ has $\beth_0$ components and $\beth_1$ path-components

where $\beth_0 = \aleph_0$ and $\beth_1 = 2^{\aleph_0}$. You may assume continuum hypothesis.

Comment: For the second: the topologist's sine curve $\{(x,\sin(1/x)\ |\ x\in (0,1)\}$ together with $\{0\}\times ([-1,1]\backslash\mathbb{Q})$ is connected but has uncountably many path components. To get countably many components simply add discrete countable space. I don't know the answer for the first one unfortunately.

Comment: Why use the gimel notations when $\aleph_0$ and $\mathfrak{c}$ will do just as well?

Comment: @Henno It's my preference.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma: Beth, actually, not gimel.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott yes, oops. I’m more familiar with the Arabic script, but that isn’t used in set theory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $X=A\sqcup \mathbb{N}$, where $A$ is an uncountable set, and open sets are precisely subsets $V$ disjoint from $A$ and subsets $U\subseteq X$ such that there exists $n\in \mathbb{N}$ with $m\in U$ for all $m\geq n$.

Then if a clopen set intersects non-trivially with $A$, it must contain $A$.  Thus $A$ is a quasicomponent of $X$.  Thus $X$ has countably many quasicomponents.

Any subset of $A$ of cardinality greater than $1$, is not connected, as the subset inherits the discrete topology.  Thus the elements of $A$ are connected components and there are uncountably many of them.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to @tkf's answer, I found an elementary example as a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^2$. Namely:

$$
(\mathbb{R} \setminus \mathbb{Q}) × \{0\} \cup \bigcup \{\mathbb{R} × \{1/n\} : n \in \mathbb{N}\}
$$

Here, the points lying on the x-axis are uncountable and totally disconnected, yet they form a whole quasicomponent.

Comment: Just saw this. You managed to get a much more concrete example than mine by having a copy of $\mathbb{R}$ for each $n\in \mathbb{N}$, instead of a point (+1).

Comment: How can you show that they are in the same quasicomponent?